# How to shift values in list of lists python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

i have the list:

```
list = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

How can i get next output:

```
listOutput = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]
```

How to sort or append by index, because values in first list can be changed dynamically?

Thank you!

Comment: Is *shift* the right word for this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hobbled yourself by naming your own variable `list`, preventing access to [the built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). If you give it a more sensible name:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

then you can easily transpose with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), and use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert each resulting tuple into a list:

```
>>> map(list, zip(*lst))
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Note that in Python 3.x `map` [produces an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), not a list, so you would need to wrap another `list` call around it (`list(map(...))`) or use a list comprehension, if you really need the complete list.

Comment: or `list(map...` for python3